# F9 key is not working in Android Studio - Debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, keyboard

My F9 key on keyboard is not working to "Resume Program" while debugging. Other F keys work. F9 does nothing. It seems more of a Windows question. But it could be something with Android Studio. Help?

Answer (score 1):

You can change Android Studio Debug setting, Steps is like
File | Setting | Keymap | Main menu | Run
you can set Resume Program for F9

Answer (score 0):

Go to AndroidStudio preferences> Keymap > Main Menu > Run > Run to Cursor:

Check which button is assigned here
You can change this as well to your favorite